# Was the Quran intended for a single view?

Tags: quran, tafseer, quran-translation

Was the Quran intended for a single view?  Or was it intended that the Quran have multiple views.

For example, when reading a book, people get out of it only what they have experienced in their own life.  For example, if a person has only experienced sadness in his life, and reads a book which starts off with a person with a sad life and ends up with a happy life.  The person reading it will generally remember the sad part more as he can relate to it.

On the other side of the coin, if a person who has only experience happiness in his life reads the same book, he will not be able to relate to the sad starting of the book and will generally only remember the happy ending of the book.

On a diff coin altogether, if a person has experienced sadness and worked hard to become happy, he will be able to related to everything in the book and will experience the sadness and happyness he reads in the book.

This is what I mean by multiple views.

Is the quran supposed to be like this?  i.e. you can only relate to those parts of the quran which you have experienced in your life?  The other parts just end up going over your head as you can't relate, just as they do with a normal book, if you can't to certain parts of a book.

Or is the quran intended for a single view?  i.e. you must know why when where and how each and every part of the quran was revealed for you to understand it and that it should never be read using your own experiences to translate the meaning of what you're reading in the quran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salam Alaikum my religious brother or sister

Suppose a person has a sad life. When he/she is reading a book it's true that the sad parts of the book is perceived better by him/her, but I mean human imagination is so strong that one can live with the characters and experiences.

In the Holy Qur'an, we must look deeper into the issue. The Quran is the book of guidance. The Quran is the book of life. It is not like a story book that one can read it on the stage of life and after that point, the book aside. If you agree with me on this issue that human life is full of different experiences. Sometimes a person is in love (like Yusuf prophet story), is sometimes rich (like Sulaiman prophet), sometimes poor and sick (like Ayub prophet), sometimes exposed to the divine will (like Ibrahim prophet), sometimes get angry and abandon his people (like Yunus prophet), ....

For each of those situations where you enter, the Quran (that belongs to  all ages and all centuries) can advise you well. These are just the appearance of the Quran. The Quran has the truth that lies in its depth, by Refering to them even most of the failures and disappointments can be avoided.

Begging prayers.